# RecyclerView not updating after adding when data was empty

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-adapter

I'm facing a strange problem when using the recylerview inside a linearlayout inside a cardview. It works perfectly when the initial data I'm passing into the adapter/recyclerview is not empty. But when I try to add an item dynamically (when the initial data was empty), the adapter set's the items, call's notifyDataSetChanged, but the recyclerview stays empty.

If I add the data dynamically, when the initial Collection was not empty, it works perfectly. It's working on other views as well. Anybody an idea what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance!

The XML file:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarComposer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:title="@string/title_timeline"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
            >

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/refreshLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/intercomsdk_white">

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:background="#E1E2E4">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <include android:id="@+id/messageCardView" layout="@layout/item_timeline_message"/>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        card_view:cardElevation="3sp"
                        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:id="@+id/commentRecyclerView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:background="#E1E2E4"
                                tools:listitem="@layout/item_timeline_comment"
                                android:layout_above="@+id/commentContainer"
                                android:minHeight="10dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/commentContainer"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:background="@color/chatWhite">

                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/commentTextField"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:textColorHint="@color/chatTextGray"
                                    android:textSize="14dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="0.8"
                                    android:hint="@string/commentInputHint" />

                                <ImageButton
                                    android:id="@+id/sendButton"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Verstuur"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_send_button"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                    android:tint="@color/chatSendButtonTint"
                                    android:background="@color/chatWhite"
                                    />

                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

The activity:

```
public class TimelineMessageActivity extends BaseActivity implements TimelineMessagePresenter.ViewInterface {

    private TimelineMessagePresenter presenter;
    private TimelineCommentAdapter adapter;

    private TimelineDataManager timelineDataManager;
    private NetworkClientInterface timelineNetworkClient;
    private UserSettingsStoreInterface userSettingsStore;

    private FragmentTimelineMessageBinding binding;
    private Menu menu;
    public int messageId;

    private List<TimelineCommentModel> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.userSettingsStore = new UserSettingsStore(getModel().getEnvironment());
        this.timelineNetworkClient = new NetworkClient(getModel().getEnvironment(), getModel().getCredentialStore());
        this.timelineDataManager = new TimelineDataManager(getModel().getTimelineStore(), timelineNetworkClient);

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.fragment_timeline_message);

        adapter = new TimelineCommentAdapter(new TimelineCommentAdapter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void didClickProfileImage(TimelineCommentModel item) {

            }

            @Override
            public void didClickMention(int userId) {
                presenter.didClickMention(userId);
            }
        }, getModel());

        SlideInBottomAnimatorAdapter animatorAdapter = new SlideInBottomAnimatorAdapter(adapter, binding.commentRecyclerView);
        binding.commentRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new SlideInOutLeftItemAnimator(binding.commentRecyclerView));
        binding.commentRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));

        binding.commentRecyclerView.setAdapter(animatorAdapter);
        binding.commentRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        binding.refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> presenter.refreshMessage());
        binding.refreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        presenter = new TimelineMessagePresenter(getModel(), getRouter(), this.timelineDataManager);
        if(getIntent().getIntExtra("message_id", 0) > 0){
            presenter.setMessageId(getIntent().getIntExtra("message_id", 0));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        presenter = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        presenter.attachView(this);
        presenter.refreshMessage();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        presenter.detachView();

        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void setComments(List<TimelineCommentModel> items) {

        for(TimelineCommentModel model : items) {
            this.comments.add(model);
        }

        adapter.setItems(this.comments);
        binding.refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(int title){
        this.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(this.getString(title));
    }

    @Override
    public void setEditText(String text) {
        binding.commentTextField.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void setButtonEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        binding.sendButton.setEnabled(enabled);
        binding.sendButton.setAlpha((float) (enabled ? 1.0 : 0.5));
    }

    @Override
    public void didSendComment() {
        binding.commentTextField.setText("");
        presenter.refreshMessage();
    }

    public void setMessageId(int messageId){
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    public void didClickMention(int userId){
        getRouter().openUri(Uri.parse("flexappeal://users/"+userId));
    }

    public void didClickDeleteButton(int id){
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.confirm_delete_message));
        dialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, (dialogInterface, i) -> {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        });
        dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, (dialogInterface, i) -> {
            presenter.didClickDeleteButton(id);
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void didClickBackButton(){
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

The presenter:

```
public class TimelineMessagePresenter extends BasePresenter<TimelineMessagePresenter.ViewInterface> {

    interface ViewInterface extends BasePresenter.ViewInterface {
        void setComments(List<TimelineCommentModel> items);

        void setTitle(int title);
        void didSendComment();

        void setButtonEnabled(boolean enabled);
        void setEditText(String text);

        void didClickBackButton();
    }

    private TimelineViewModel message = new TimelineViewModel();
    private List<TimelineCommentModel> comments = new ArrayList<>();
    private String commentMessage;

    private int messageId;

    @NonNull private final TimelineDataManager dataManager;

    private final boolean needsRefresh = true;

    public TimelineMessagePresenter(@NonNull Model model, @NonNull RouterInterface router, @NonNull TimelineDataManager dataManager) {
        super(model, router);
        this.dataManager = dataManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachView() {
        super.onAttachView();

        getModel().getEventBus().register(this);

        updateView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachView() {
        getModel().getEventBus().unregister(this);

        super.onDetachView();
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(SocketEvent event) {
        // TODO: handle new comment in message event as soon as we integrate realtime timeline as well
    }

    public void updateView() {
        if (getView() != null) {
            getView().setEditText(commentMessage);
            getView().setComments(comments);
        }
    }

    private boolean shouldEnableButton() {
        return (commentMessage != null && commentMessage.length() > 0);
    }

    public void didClickHighFiveButton(){
        dataManager.postLike(messageId).subscribe(message -> {
            refreshMessage();
        }, error -> {
            Log.w("TimelinePresenter", error);
        });
    }

    public void didClickSendCommentButton(){
        this.dataManager.postComment(messageId, commentMessage).subscribe(result -> {
            getView().didSendComment();
        }, error -> {
            Log.w("TimelinePresenter", error);
        });
    }

    public void refreshMessage() {
        dataManager.getMessageDetail(messageId).subscribe(messageDetail ->{
            this.comments.clear();

            this.message = createViewModelForTimelineMessage(messageDetail);
            if(messageDetail.getComments() != null){
                for(Comments comment : messageDetail.getComments()) {
                    this.comments.add(createViewModelForTimelineComment(comment));
                }
            }
            updateView();
        }, error -> {
            Log.w("TimelineMessagePresenter", error);
        });

    }

    private TimelineCommentModel createViewModelForTimelineComment(Comments c) {
        TimelineCommentModel vm = new TimelineCommentModel();
        vm.commentId = c.getId();
        vm.createdBy = c.getUser();
        vm.createdAt = c.getCreated_at_diff();
        vm.message = c.getMessage();

        return vm;
    }

    public void didChangeMessage(CharSequence message) {
        this.commentMessage = message.toString();

        if (getView() != null) {
            getView().setButtonEnabled(shouldEnableButton());
        }
    }

    public void setMessageId(int messageId){
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    public void didClickMention(int userId){
        getRouter().openUri(Uri.parse("flexappeal://users/"+userId));
    }

    public void didClickDeleteButton(int id){
        dataManager.deleteMessage(id).subscribe(aBoolean -> {
            getView().didClickBackButton();
        }, error -> {
            getView().didClickBackButton();
        });
    }
}
```

The adapter:

```
class TimelineCommentAdapter extends BindingRecyclerViewAdapter<TimelineCommentModel, ItemTimelineCommentBinding> {

    private final Listener listener;
    private final Model model;

    public TimelineCommentAdapter(Listener listener, Model model) {
        super(R.layout.item_timeline_comment);
        this.listener = listener;
        this.model = model;
    }

    public interface Listener {
        void didClickProfileImage(TimelineCommentModel item);
        void didClickMention(int userId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void bind(ItemTimelineCommentBinding binding, TimelineCommentModel item, int position) {

        Picasso.with(binding.getRoot().getContext()).load(item.createdBy.getProfileImage()).into(binding.userProfileImage);
        binding.userProfileImage.setOnClickListener(view -> listener.didClickProfileImage(item));

        binding.userFullName.setText(item.createdBy.getFullName());
        binding.ago.setText(item.createdAt);

    }

    @Override
    protected void recycle(ItemTimelineCommentBinding binding) {
        Picasso.with(binding.getRoot().getContext()).cancelRequest(binding.userProfileImage);
    }
}
```

The BindingRecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public abstract class BindingRecyclerViewAdapter<T, B extends ViewDataBinding>
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BindingRecyclerViewAdapter<T, B>.ViewHolder> {

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public final B binding;

        public ViewHolder(B binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
            this.itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (onItemClickListener != null) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    onItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, position);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View itemView, int position);
    }

    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    private List<T> items;

    private final int layoutRes;

    public BindingRecyclerViewAdapter(@LayoutRes int layoutRes) {
        this(layoutRes, null, null);
    }

    public BindingRecyclerViewAdapter(@LayoutRes int layoutRes, Collection<T> items) {
        this(layoutRes, items, null);
    }

    public BindingRecyclerViewAdapter(@LayoutRes int layoutRes, Collection<T> items, OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.layoutRes = layoutRes;
        this.items = (items == null) ? new ArrayList<>() : new ArrayList<>(items);
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        B binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), layoutRes, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        T item = items.get(position);
        bind(holder.binding, item, position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(ViewHolder holder) {
        recycle(holder.binding);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    protected abstract void bind(B binding, T item, int position);
    protected abstract void recycle(B binding);

    public OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener() {
        return onItemClickListener;
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    public List<T> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(Collection<T> items) {
        this.items.clear();

        if (items != null) {
            this.items.addAll(items);
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: After adding an item try to recreate the adapter object and re apply it to the recycler view and see what happens.

Comment: Where you have called `setComments()` ?? and paste your `getModel()` method. Better to share full code so it will be easy for us to help you out..!!

Comment: The setComments is called from the presenter after loading the data from the data store @jankigadhiya. I've updated the question and added the code. The getModel is just a method which returns an object with all the global stores and datamanagers in it. It isn't used yet in the Adapter,

Comment: I will not be able to understand until you share the full code. Means your activty/fragmet + adapater class. WHOLE..!!

Comment: Okay, see updated code...

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a reference problem, when you are setting the comments like this: `this.comments = items;` the reference from the `List` of comments that were added to the `Adapter` were switched with a different `List` of items (but the `Adapter` still has the reference to the old, empty `List`).

So to solve this, instead of replacing the comments with a new `List` of items, try adding the items to the comments with a for-loop. Just loop through all the items and add them to the comments like this:

```
for(TimelineCommentModel model: items) {
    this.comments.add(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I did try that solution, but it isn't working. A quick debug in the adapter shows that the items are passed into the adapter as well. Even with the code I used already.

Answer (score 0):

if this will not help then you must invalidate scrollview coz you are placing recyclerview in it

```
public void setComments(List<TimelineCommentModel> items) {
    this.comments.clear();
    this.comments.addAll(items);
    adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
    binding.refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunatly not working :( Already did give the invalidate a try to trigger the refresh of the complete view (through binding.invalidateAll()) but didn't help.

Comment: try to call invalidate() and requestLayout() on scrollview in runonuithread after set comments